# Uneven spacing of headers on one line using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to space the headers above the form unevenly on one line and not really sure what the best way to do this using HTML and CSS. I have used span tags and padding in the past but this works differently in different browsers and does not line up correctly. Im sure there is a better way then wrapping all of the headers in span tags. Thanks so much for your help. I have attached an image of what I would like to achieve.[image]

Comment: What do you god so far ? You can use the <br> tag.

Comment: I haven't started working on the HTML because I am looking for the best possible strategy. The <br> tag will break the line. I need "Card Type" "Quantity" "# of Colors" to be spaced appropriately and I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a table, the cells will auto size to the content in them. Tables are still useful when dealing purely with tabular data. Alternatively, you can assign a class to each header cell to set specific widths.

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">

<tr>

    <td>one</td>
    <td>this one needs more space and will grow</td>
    <td>this guy isn't as long</td>
    <td>short</td>

</tr>
```

​

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JdSy2/

Comment: Thanks this works great, I have never used tables before but this is exactly what I am looking for.